# Assign a unique ID to tinyMCE image uploader

Tags: php, tinymce

So I am using the tinyMCE WYSIWYG, I am using their image uploader script from their website and managed to get it working. The only problem is I want each image file to have a unique filename but cant work it out. I've tried to cut some of the code out that didn't seem relevant.

```
 reset ($_FILES);
 $temp = current($_FILES);
 if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
/*
  If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
  the configuration and enable the following two headers.
*/
// header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
// header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

// Sanitize input
if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
    return;
}

// Verify extension
if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
    return;
}

// Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
$filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
$sg_upload_image = move_uploaded_file(uniqid($temp['tmp_name']), $filetowrite);

// Determine the base URL
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? "https://" : "http://";
$baseurl = $protocol . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), "/") . "/";

// Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
// Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
// { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
echo json_encode(array('location' => $baseurl . $filetowrite));
} else {
// Notify editor that the upload failed
header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is changing this code :

```
$filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
```

`$temp['name']` is the name of the file. You could do something like that :

```
$fName = pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '_' . time() . '.' pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$filetowrite = $imageFolder . '/' . $fName;
```

Now, the filename have the orginal name with the timestamp of the upload.